# Why did this character want to wait?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part II*, just as Voldemort is about to give the order for the advance on Hogwarts, one of the Death Eaters stops him and asks whether they should wait for something or someone. He suddenly stops when Voldemort glares at him, and then Voldemort begins the attack.

Who or what exactly was it that this character wanted to wait for?

Comment: Book or movie version?

Comment: @Michael - since OP asks about "Part II" - its the movie. It was Pius Thicknesse. I don't know that we know for certain what he was going to say from what is in the film - perhaps he was going to say they could wait for Harry to be turned over (since Voldemort had just offered a deal by which he would not attack in exchange for the students / staff turning Potter over). IMO it's an example showing just how bloodthirsty Voldemort and Bellatrix are 
 https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/harry-potter-and-the-deathly-hollows-part-2-2011.pdf

Comment: Good point - my eyes managed to skip over that helpful wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few minutes earlier Voldemort issued an ultimatum to the occupants of Hogwarts Castle, give up Harry Potter and face no attack.

> **VOLDEMORT (V.O.)**
> *I wish you no harm. I have great
> respect for the students of
> Hogwarts. I was once one myself
> after all. I ask for but one
> thing and if granted no magical
> blood shall be spilt...*
>
> [For a moment they stand, hung in silence...]
>
> *Give me Harry Potter. Do this and
> none shall be harmed. Give me
> Harry Potter and I shall leave
> Hogwarts untouched. Give me Harry
> Potter and you will be rewarded.*
>
> <sub><sup>[HARRY POTTER AND THE DEATHLY HALLOWS - PART 2: Original Screenplay](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/harry-potter-and-the-deathly-hollows-part-2-2011.pdf)</sup></sub>

Pius Thicknesse (Voldemort's patsy) is merely pointing this out to Voldemort. Big V, on the other hand, is under no illusions that they're going to offer up Potter. On arrival he finds serried ranks of giant statues and a great big shield erected to defy him.

> **THICKNESSE:**  *But, my Lord, shouldn’t we wait --*
>
> [Voldemort’s eyes shift, killing the remainder of
> Thicknesse’s sentence before it can escape his throat.
> Bellatrix’s eyes narrow in contempt. Chilled, Thicknesse
> looks away. Then -- as if burying a knife deep in the
> heart of an enemy... Bellatrix drops her arm.]

You'll note that later in the script when Voldemort no longer has any use for Thicknesse, he kills him without batting an eyelid. Clearly he has no time for cowards and nay-sayers.

> **VOLDEMORT:** *Nagini. Come.*
>
> [Voldemort begins to slip away, BLASTING anyone who stands
> in his way. Pius Thicknesse comes INTO VIEW. His eyes
> widen. Voldemort raises his wand and, with callous
> disregard, executes him as well. As those ahead part for
> him and Nagini, we return to...]

Comment: @ Congrats on reaching 500k reputation

Comment: @TheMadHatter - Cheers. It's much appreciated

Comment: Wasn't Pius Thicknesse also under the Imperius curse throughout? Although the movies don't do a good job of illustrating it.